# Print lines with pattern found outside square brackets

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

Good day,

I was wondering how to print lines that contain data inside and outside of square brackets. But, the pattern is only found outside the square bracket.

Pattern `lipsum2`

**Expected Input**

```
[lipsum1; limpsum6; lipsum1] lipsum2;[lipsum9; limpsum1; lipsum1] lipsum2
[lipsum1; limpsum7; lipsum1] lipsum3;[lipsum10; limpsum1; lipsum1] lipsum3
[lipsum1; limpsum2; lipsum1] lipsum4;[lipsum12; limpsum1; lipsum1] lipsum4
[lipsum1; limpsum2; lipsum1] lipsum5;[lipsum2; limpsum1; lipsum1] lipsum5
```

**Expected Output**

```
[lipsum1; limpsum6; lipsum1] lipsum2;[lipsum9; limpsum1; lipsum1] lipsum2
```

Thank so much in advance for any clue.

*Note: I am not interested on sed. Thanks again.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below grep command,

```
grep -P 'lipsum2(?![^\[\]]*\])' file
```

Matches `lipsum2` only if it isn't followed by any char but not of `[` or `]` zero or more times then a `]` symbol.

```
lipsum2                  'lipsum2'
(?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
  [^\[\]]*                 any character except: '\[', '\]' (0 or
                           more times)
  \]                       ']'
)                        end of look-ahead
```

**OR**

```
grep -P '^(?!.*\[[^\[\]]*lipsum2[^\[\]]*]).*lipsum2.*' file
```

This `(?!.*\[[^\[\]]*lipsum2[^\[\]]*])` negative lookahead asserts that there isn't a string `lipsum2` present inside the `[]` braces. With this condition, regex engine would match the lines which contain `lipsum2` (not within `[]`) string.

Comment: Thank too much. It works smoothly, Can I ask you how the first one works?

Answer (score 1):

Well the question is vague, but this will do it

```
awk '$NF ~ /lipsum2/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{s=$0; gsub(/\[.[^][]*\]/,"") ; if($0~/lipsum2/) {print s} }' file
```

Explanation:

```
s=$0 :                      Save the current line to variable s because gsub changes $0
gsub(/\[.[^][]*\]/,"") :    Do a global substitution, look for [ till ] but cannot contain [ or ] in between using inversion in character group , eg [^][]
```

The rest is self explanatory

Comment: Thank too much. It works properly. Would it be too much if I ask you how it works? A little explanation for dummies, something like that : )